# webview scrolling issue android

Tags: android, webview

hi how to set scroll length to web view in android?

i wanted to scroll web screen for fixed length. I'm displaying a web page in web view and i adjusted web content using div tag to scroll  horizontally. till here no problem and i want to add feature to webview  that once user tap the screen horizontally it should move up to fixed length to the right.

Comment: Sure looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308246/how-to-scroll-screen-by-fixed-length-in-webview - great info provided there too...

Comment: @Klaus i cant delete it!!! still no ans!!!

Comment: So? It's still a duplicate. Also, it's pretty hard to understand what you want. So you're unlikely to get any answers.

Comment: @Klaus i saw your profile .. you had some issue related to scrolling .. but I couldn't get actually what I wanted..Do you saw any ebook reader app ? same scrolling behaviour is needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to do it with JavaScript? When handle a tap on Android side, and then use

```java
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:....")
```

to adjust scroll offset of browser window.

Comment: You don't know JS at all, or just don't know how to scroll page at client side?

Comment: No, you need not. Try to do WebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(123);") for example, and you'll get javascript alert window. With loadUrl you can run actually any script in already loaded page context.

Comment: @Olegas i thought we need to declare JS function in html page then only we can call that function WebView.loadUrl("javascript:function();") .. Right no?

Comment: No, you can decalre a function and call it (or already declared ones) directly through loadUrl().